Solution to SDE can't explode if drift coefficient is polynomially growing.
I just got introduced to SDEs and am trying to solve the following exercise:
"
Let $\mu: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable and polynomially growing, let $\sigma: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be globally Lipschitz, and let $\xi \in L^p(P|_{\mathcal{F}_0}; | \cdot |)$ for $2 \leq p < \infty$. Prove or disprove: $\mu$ and $\sigma$ can be such that
$$
\exists T \in (0,\infty): dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t, \quad t \in [0,T], \quad X_0 = \xi
$$
holds on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P, (\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\in[0,T]})$ such that, for $S_r := \inf\{t \in [0,T) : X_t \notin (-r,r)\}$ $(r > 0)$, we have
$$
P(\forall k \in \mathbb{N} : S_k < T) > 0
$$"
If we assume that such a solution exist then we know that $X_t$ would get arbitrarily large on a non-null set. The existence and uniqueness theorem that we looked at also tells us that $\sup_{t \in [0,T]} \mathbb{E}[X_t]< \infty$ which would obviously contradict this assumption. My problem is that the exsistence theorem assumes that $\mu$ is globally Lipschitz, which must not be given here, so I'm stuck. Could maybe someone point me to a result that would be useful here? Thanks!
